# tracking activities on linux system?

Tags: linux

Is there any application that can track our activities on Linux system, actually I want to know my history of what I'm doing.

```
Example :
opened Firefox at 10: 20 am
opened gramps at 10 : 50 an
```

So we can see our these actives and we can know what we have done on this time, how many long and etc.
There such application for tracing time like Project Hamster, but its not automatically track what we are doing.
or maybe there is and advanced one that can include what we are doing inside application like :

In Firefox opened google.com at 10:20 PM
opened yahoo.com at 04:00 AM

Comment: What is a "unix-like" system?

Answer (score -2):

For tracking activities, just use this command in the terminal
        `top`
This will give you all necessary details regarding CPU usage,etc.

Comment: This is a solution to a different question.